# Partial matching elasticsearch rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm currently using elasticsearch to find a client by name, it works if you input the whole name. However I need to be able to search even if the customer only inputted the first two letters of a name. I'm attempting to use a partial match, although I get this error.

```
AdGroup.__elasticsearch__.create_index!  force:true
[!!!] Index does not exist (Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound)
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer on field 
[client_name] must be set when search_analyzer is 
set"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse   
mapping [ad_group]: analyzer on field [client_name] must be set when 
 search_analyzer is set","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer on field [client_name] must be set when search_analyzer is set"}},"status":400}
```

My models/ad-group.rb

```
class AdGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Elasticsearch::Model
   include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

 settings analysis: {
  filter: {
    ngram_filter: { type: "nGram", min_gram: 2, max_gram: 12 }
  },
  analyzer: {
        index_ngram_analyzer: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: ['lowercase', 'ngram_filter']
        },
        search_ngram_analyzer: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: ['lowercase']
        }
    }
} do
mapping do 
    indexes :published
    indexes :client_name,:type => "string", index_analyzer:   "index_ngram_analyzer", search_analyzer: "search_ngram_analyzer"
    indexes :created_at
    indexes :updated_at
    indexes :preview_updated_at
end
end
```

controller/adgroups

```
class AdGroupsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      if params[:client_name]
       @ad_groups = AdGroup.search(params[:client_name]).page(params[:page]).results
      else
          @ad_groups = AdGroup.includes(:client).where(is_template: false).paginate(:page =>  params[:page]).order('id DESC')
      end

    end
end
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining a `search_analyzer` and an `index_analyzer`, but not a default `analyzer`. Take a look to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html).

It will work if you modify the line of code where you set the analyzers for the `client_name` to:

```
    indexes :client_name,:type => "string", analyzer:   "index_ngram_analyzer", search_analyzer: "search_ngram_analyzer"
```

In this way, it will take the default `analyzer` at index time, while it will pick up the `search_analyzer` at query time.

Comment: thank you ! That solved that issue although still can't get it to do a partial match.

Comment: What are you using for querying? Could you post your method?

Comment: BTW, if you want a match with the first input characters, I would better use a `edge_ngram` filter. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html

Comment: just edit my question adding the controller where I am doing the query.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how much this will help, but I had to deal with this for a client that wanted to be able to search for businesses.  Granted this was over a year ago so I don't remember the details, but I had to make this change in `business_profiles_controller.rb`.

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @business_profiles = BusinessProfile.search(params[:query], fields: [{ name: :word_middle }])
  else
    @business_profiles = BusinessProfile.all
  end
end
```

The flag `:word_middle` allowed us to search within the `:name` field for every business profile.

I hope this was of some help.

[Using SearchKick and ElasticSearch in Rails 4](http://www.munocreative.com/nerd-notes/tutor-portal)